# Killing a mysqld process causes another mysqld process to immediately start

Tags: mamp, mysql

I'm having an issue starting the MySQL server using MAMP, and the problem may be that I can't seem to kill all my mysqld proceses before I open MAMP. Starting MAMP creates a second, conflicting mysqld process. Before opening MAMP, I use killall -9 mysqld, but that only creates another mysqld process with a different processid. Any idea what's causing the mysqld process to be created? I installed mysql after installing MAMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled mysql, and then everything worked.